# Solve differential equation with unknown coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-polynomial

**Problem**

> We have the differential equation: $$x^{(3)}(t)+(\alpha+\beta) x''(t)+(1+\alpha\beta)x'(t)=u(t) $$
> $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real constants.
>
> With $u(t)=\sin(2t)$ and the assumption $|\alpha-\beta|<2$ use the guessing method to show that the complete real solution is on the form
>
> $$x(t)=c_1+c_2 e^{at}\cos(\omega t)+c_3e^{at}\sin(\omega t)+A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t) $$
>
> And determine the real parameters, $a, \omega, A, B$.

**My progress**

Let's first try to find the solution the homogenous differential equation $$x^{(3)}(t)+(\alpha+\beta) x''(t)+(1+\alpha\beta)x'(t)=0 $$

We write up the characteristic polynomial

$$\lambda^3+\lambda^2(\alpha+\beta)+\lambda(1+\alpha\beta)=0 $$

$$\lambda(\lambda^2+\lambda(\alpha+\beta)+(1+\alpha\beta)) =0$$

But, since I don't know the exact values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I can't find the roots to the characteristic polynomial, and therefore I can't determine the complete solution to the homogenous differential equation.

I don't know how to get further with this problem form here, but it seems like I'm missing something important that needs to be understood. Or maybe I should use another method instead?

Comment: Factorise $\lambda$ thats the first thing to do then you have a quadratic equation that you can solve.

Comment: @Aryadeva After factoring I see that $0$ is definitely a solution. But there must be two more, since the characteristic polynomial is of order 3, right?

Comment: Of order two Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lambda^3+\lambda^2(\alpha+\beta)+\lambda(1+\alpha\beta)=0$$
Factorize $\lambda$
$$\lambda (\lambda^2+\lambda(\alpha+\beta)+(1+\alpha\beta))=0$$
$$\implies \lambda=0$$
And the solution is $y_1=c_1e^{\lambda t}=c_1$
and
$$ \lambda^2+\lambda(\alpha+\beta)+(1+\alpha\beta)=0$$
Try to solve the quadratic equation. Now evaluate the discriminant of the quadratic equation and don't forget that $|\alpha -\beta|<2$
$$\Delta =(\alpha +\beta)^2-4(1+\alpha\beta)$$
$$\Delta =(\alpha -\beta)^2-4$$
$$\Delta =(\alpha -\beta)-2)(\alpha -\beta)+2)$$
So that:
$$|\alpha -\beta|<2 \implies \Delta <0$$
Then the solutions of the quadratic equation are complex:
$$\lambda_{1,2}=\dfrac {-(\alpha+\beta)\pm i\sqrt {|\Delta|}}{2}$$
Now you can deduce the solution to the homogeneous differential equation:
$$x(t)=c_1+c_2e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_3e^{\lambda_2 t}$$
You can use Euler's formula in order to reformulate the solution $y(t)$ with sine and cosine functions.
$$ \boxed {x(t)=c_1+e^{-(\alpha +\beta)t/2}(c_2 \cos (\sqrt {|\Delta |}t/2)+c_3 \sin (\sqrt {|\Delta |}t/2))}$$
You can easily deduce that:
$$\omega =\dfrac 12\sqrt {|\Delta |}=\dfrac  12\sqrt { |(\alpha -\beta)^2-4|}$$
$$a=-\dfrac {(\alpha +\beta)}2$$

---

For the inhomogeneous part trye
$$x(t)=A \sin (2t)+B \cos (2t)$$
$$x'(t)=2A \cos (2t)-2B \sin (2t)$$
$$x''(t)=-4A \sin (2t)-4B \cos (2t)$$
$$x'''(t)=-8A \cos (2t)+8B\sin (2t)$$
Plug these in the DE and find the cosntants $A,B$.

Comment: I made some edits using your hints and I think I'm on the right track. Thank you very much for the help, I will try to take it from here myself. Have a good day, I wish I could give you more than one upvote.

Comment: You're welcome Carl. Have a good day too. @Carl

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to the inhomogenous solution now and have gotten a very nasty looking equation. I have to determine the coefficients $A$ and $B$ such that the equation is true, but I don't know how to come further. Can you give me some help again?

Comment: I added some lines @Carl

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but isn't this what I have already done (in the bottom of my question)? My problem is that I don't know how to determine the constants, $A$ and $B$. @Aryadeva

Comment: Collect all the terms of cosine functions and set it equal to zero. Collect all the terms with sine functions and set it equal to $1$ Then you have a system of two equations in function of $\alpha, \beta$ and solve. @Carl